# Matrix (correct) notation

Tags: matrices, notation

Say I have a real $m \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{M}$. Shall I write $\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ or $\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}$?
What is commonly accepted and most beautiful and correct version?

Moreover, shall I use an italic bold font like $\boldsymbol{M}$ or vertical bold $\mathbf{M}$?  And same question for vectors: I personally dislike $\mathbf{x}$ and prefer $\boldsymbol{x}$. What is commonly and beautifully accepted?

---

In conclusion, if I got it right, $\boldsymbol{M}\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and  $M_{i,j}\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think Peter says it good, and Irish's is the way I've seen it too.  I learned my upper Linear ALgebra from Cooperstein's Advanced Linear Algebra, and he uses the notation Irish used, but I've a friend who read Axler's LInear Algebra Done Right and I think it's different there too.  The key is once you use it stick with it.  THen there is no confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual notation is $M\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}$ or $M\in {\mathrm M}_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)$. The bold face or italics is up to you, and depends on the context of what you're writing, and if you want to distinguish certain elements by such details. The "beautiful" part is simply subjective. I prefer $\bf x,y$ for vectors, and not-so-italicized capitals for matrices. In particular, there is no "correct" notation, but of course you won't be denoting matrices by the same symbols you denote vectors or scalars, say. The usual convention is upper case first or close-to-m alphabet letters for matrices, $A,B,C,M,N,\ldots$, lower-case for vectors, $a,b,v,w,x,y,\ldots$ and greek for scalars, $\lambda,\eta,\ldots$.

Comment: What was your reason to switch $m$ and $n$?

Comment: @VedranŠego I am used to writing it that way. I didn't  even notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I see this very often and was taught this:
$$M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$$
If it's just a square matrix, then
$$M_n(\mathbb{F})$$
where $\mathbb{F}$ is an arbitrary field.
These are the sets of matrices.  For an arbitrary matrix, say like your example.  Then I would see
$$\mathbf{A}\in{M_{m,n}(\mathbb{F})}$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is your matrix.  I like the bold personally, but it is not required I don't believe.

Comment: Ok, I am an engineer, therefore I believe the convention is slightly different..

Comment: .. since I am not familiar with the $\mathbf{A}\in{M_{m,n}(\mathbb{F})}$

Comment: Thank you...  I'll be okay...  :)  It would seem Mr. Tamaroff is much more thorough then me anyway.

Comment: Mr. Tamaroff cleared my doubt among $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{m,n}$ ;)